# The Query Results from History seems to have a hard time displaying

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to analyze a query through the history, but the Query Result pane keeps having status 'Loading'. How can I fix this ?

[Screenshot from the Snowflake GU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eevxO.png)

Comment: I find sometimes the UI overheats, after leaving it open for weeks, and now and then a good old turn it on/off again (aka page reload) helps..

Comment: It can take some time to load the results.  You may also check your network traffic just to make sure all is returning smoothly (no failed network requests).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding LIMIT 1000 to your query.

Comment: The browser does not load all the results in one go. It pageants the results..

Comment: You are absolutely right and I will amend my response.  I inspected the HTML and network activity for a large result set and could see that indeed only a few rows were rendered in HTML, and that the results were paginated at the network level as well.  Nevertheless, result sets with LIMIT always load in equal time or faster in my experience, including in my testing just now.

Comment: agreed, limits allows the query to complete faster, if there are no orders or aggregations, as not all data for those cases needs to be loaded, but what the user is describing is a failure of the web ui, which is not related to the query it self.